# Trying to understand NULL operator in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to see a breakdown of the total dollar business that each vendor has done (indirectly via the distributor) with each customer, where I'm trying not to use the `Inner Join` Syntax. I basically don't understand the difference between the two outputs produced by the two queries shown below:

Query1

```
select customers.cust_id, vendors.vend_id, sum(OrderItems.item_price*OrderItems.quantity) as  total_business from
(((Vendors left outer join products
on vendors.vend_id = products.prod_id)
left outer join OrderItems
on products.prod_id = OrderItems.prod_id)
left outer join Orders
on OrderItems.order_num = Orders.order_num)
left outer join Customers
on Orders.cust_id = Customers.cust_id
group by Customers.cust_id, vendors.vend_id
order by total_business
```

I get the following output:
[image]

Query2

```
select customers.cust_id, Vendors.vend_id, sum(quantity*item_price) as total_business from
(((Vendors left outer join Products 
on Products.vend_id = Vendors.vend_id)
left outer join OrderItems --No inner joins allowed
on OrderItems.prod_id = Products.prod_id)
left outer join Orders 
on Orders.order_num = OrderItems.order_num)
left outer join Customers 
on Customers.cust_id = Orders.cust_id
where Customers.cust_id is not null -- THE ONLY DIFFERENCE BETWEEN QUERY1 AND QUERY2
group by Customers.cust_id, Vendors.vend_id
order by total_business
```

[image]

**I don't understand how there are only `NULL` `cust_id`'s associated with the 1st Output when in the 2nd Output we get some non-NULL `cust_id`s. Why doesn't the 1st Output include these non-NULL `cust_id`'s**

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you left join to a table, then filter on that table in the where clause, the join effectively changes to an inner join.  The workaround is to apply the filter as a joining condition.

In your second query, all you have to do is is change the word "where" to "and".

Answer (score 1):

Query One is joining Vendors and Products incorrectly:

`on vendors.vend_id = products.prod_id -- Vend_ID = Prod_ID`

Query Two is joining Vendors and Products correctly:

`on Products.vend_id = Vendors.vend_id -- Vend_ID = Vend_ID`

Once that is fixed, you'll get the same IDs in both queries.  Then I suggest you read Dan's answer to understand why what you were trying to do in eliminating `INNER JOIN` from the query is cancelled out by adding a `WHERE` filter to a column from the last table in the chain.